# loading pdf files from static folder into pdftron/webviewer

Tags: nuxt.js, pdftron

I am having an issue where I am unable/do not know to load pdf files from static folder into the webviewer

This is the default code:

**Component**

```
<template>
  <div class="webviewer" id="webviewer" ref="viewer"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Webviewer',
  props: {
    path: String,
    url: String,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      
    }
  },

  mounted: function () {
    import('@pdftron/webviewer').then(() => {
      WebViewer(
        {
          path: '../webviewer',
          initialDoc: this.url, //replace with pdf
        },
        this.$refs.viewer
      ).then((instance) => {
        //call apis here
      })
    })
  },
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.webviewer {
  height: 100dvh;
  width: 100dvw;
}
</style>
```

**Page code**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Webviewer
      :path="`${publicPath}webviewer`"
      url="https://pdftron.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/pl/webviewer-demo.pdf"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

**Things I tried**

I tried changing the url, different variations:

```
<!-- with bind -->
<Webviewer
        :path="`${publicPath}webviewer`"
       :url="require('@/static/books/webviewer-demo.pdf"
      />
```

```
<!-- without bind -->
 <Webviewer
        :path="`${publicPath}webviewer`"
        url="../../static/books/webviewer-demo.pdf"
      />
```

It works fine if I put any pdf url from the internet but it doesn't work when I try to get the data from my own files, any ideas/tips ?

**Errors**

[error which happens when i put file path instead of a url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Z8h.png)

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing I managed to make it work this way, my main mistake was treating the url param as if it was a path param I was doing that because it can work in css and I never ran into such an issue before, feel dumb.

**You have to put the pdf file in the static folder, it doesn't work if you put it in another folder within the static folder for reasons that I dont understand**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- url="https://pdftron.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/pl/webviewer-demo.pdf" -->
    <Webviewer
      :path="`${publicPath}webviewer`"
      url="http://localhost:3000/mthakaratqare.pdf"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

**Page code was missing return value in script section**

```
<script>
import Webviewer from '../components/Webviewer/index.vue'
export default {
  components: {
    Webviewer,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL,
    }
  },
}
</script>
```